# How to click on this button by using javascript which is mentioned in the below code

Tags: javascript, browser

Provide me the javascript which I could run in the console window such that it clicks on the button automatically.

```
<button value="1" class="button_confirm" type="submit">Confirm</button>
```

Comment: We are waiting for for JS code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give some id to button, for example **button1** and then run the code below in console :

```
document.getElementById("button1").click();
```

Comment: I cant give that an id it is loaded with the webpage. It is not my webpage bro :)

Comment: Then use document.getElementsByClassName("button_confirm")[0].click();  :)

Comment: That worked I tried but I did not place " [0] " and that might be the reason it did not work... Can you please take time to explain what that [0] indicates.

Comment: getElementsByClassName returns an array of all elements having class button_confirm, so we have to specify which element we want to work with. In this case we are calling click() on the first element of the array.

Comment: What if we dont have the array and only single element exist of that class

Comment: return type is always going to be an array, so even if you have a single element you can access that element using array index. Whenever you use getElement function in JS, always notice whether it getElement or getElements because getElements will always return an array of element where as getElement will return a single element. For example , getElementById will return single element having id which we would pass to it as an argument but getElementsByClassName will return an array.

Comment: Thank you so much that information was very useful :) Thank you once again :)

Comment: My Pleasure Karan.. we are here to share what we know.. :)